# Proper Laravel way to get a relation basing on both tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I do have 2 tables linked with each other.
Items that has an ID and quantity column, as well as Attendees that have id, item_id and some other data.

I would like to be able to see all the items that have:
a) no attendees at all.
b) less attendees than the quantity.
c) as many attendees as the quantity.

While a is easy to do with raw:

```
SELECT it.*, COUNT(att.item_id) AS atts, it.quantity as quant
      FROM items AS it
               LEFT JOIN attendees AS att on it.id = att.item_id
      GROUP BY it.id
```

and b and c can be done this way:

```
select *
from (SELECT it.*, COUNT(att.item_id) AS atts, it.quantity as quant
      FROM items AS it
               LEFT JOIN attendees AS att on it.id = att.item_id
      GROUP BY it.id) as `i.*aq`
where atts < quant; // or atts = quant
```

I cannot manage to find a way to do this thing with Eloquent.
I wanted to do it with a scope like this:

```
Item.php


public function scopeFull(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->where('quantity', '=', $this->attendees()->count());
    }
```

but it throws me an error about 'attendees'.'' not being a column name (the relation in other cases works fine though).

I really care about the code being clean, and I really do want to make it with either Eloquent models, or (less preferably) DB::selects.

Oh, and for those that just say to get all items as a collection to PHP already and filter it out - I really believe there is a clean way of achieving this via Fluent/Eloquent.

Thank y'all in advance!

EDIT:

Along with one of the answers I tried to use has() function, and while for case a it works fine, cases b and c would require an external parameter to come and see, while this solution should compare it live.

It should be something along these lines:

```
public function scopeFull(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->has('attendees', '=', 'items.quantity'); // or $this->quantity
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a properly configured relation called `attendees` on the `items` model, what you want are the [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) and [`doesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) methods

You can call these on the model itself easy enough, but if you really wanted to make scopes for them, they'd look something like this:

```
// a) no attendees at all.
public function scopeWithoutAttendees(Builder $query)
{
    return $query->doesntHave('attendees');
}

// b) less attendees than the quantity.
public function scopeFewerAttendeesThan(Builder $query, $quantity)
{
    return $query->has('attendees', '<', $quantity);
}

// c) as many attendees as the quantity.
public function scopeAttendeesCount(Builder $query, $quantity)
{
    return $query->has('attendees', '=', $quantity);
}
```

Note that `whereHas` and `whereDoesntHave` are also worth reading about there as they'll let you use closures that can add more conditions on the relations if needed.

Comment: the has/doesnthave thing is definitely helpful, however I am still struggling to get the quantity sorted as I do not want to do pass it as a parameter, but make it deduct it directly from a db.
something along these lines
```
public function scopeFull(Builder $query)
 {
  return $query->has('attendees', '=', 'items.quantity'); // or $this->quantity
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write a working solution to it. It is messy, though, so if anyone has a better idea on what to improve, please let me know.

Case b example:

```
public function scopeNotFull(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->withCount(
            [
                'attendees' => function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->whereNotNull('attendees.id');
                },
            ]
        )
                     ->havingRaw("`items`.`quantity` > `attendees_count`");
    }
```